# Установить библиотеку с помощью Composer в отдельную директорию

Tags: drupal, composer, drupal8

Drupal 8 ищет подключеные библиотеки только в определенных директориях. У меня же библиотека

```
composer require components/chosen
```

установилась в директорию `vendor/components/chosen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден здесь [composer is ignoring installer-paths configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34846777/9335078)

Как известно можно указать свою кастомную директорию с помощью 
[Custom Install Paths](https://github.com/composer/installers)

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "your/custom/path/{$name}/": ["type:drupal-library"]
    }
}
```

Но в даной библиотеки type равный component, а такой тип не поддерживает extra  "installer-paths" . И его нельзя установить в отдельную директорию.

Решением проблемы стал пакет

```
composer require oomphinc/composer-installers-extender
```

После его установки можно добавить type "component" и указать "installer-paths" по name библиотеки.

```
"extra": {
    "installer-types": ["component"],
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library", "components/chosen"],
    }
}
```